# readline() returns bracket

Tags: python, readline

I wrote some codes to get some lines from .txt like below and its keep returning lines with brackets which I did not intend. Could you help me?

codes:

```
#!/bin/python
i=1
f=open("name.txt","r")
while(i<=225):
 x=f.readline().splitlines()
 print("mol new %s.bgf"%(x))
 i+=1
f.close()
```

name.txt

```
02.ala.r49r50.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14421.f.c
04.ala.r44r45.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c48608.h.c
09.ala.r46r47.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14682.t.c
17.ala.r47r48.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c9610.th.c
18.ala.r48r49.TRK820.no_59.rnd_1.c19106.t.c
```

And it returns

```
mol new ['02.ala.r49r50.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14421.f.c'].bgf
mol new ['04.ala.r44r45.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c48608.h.c'].bgf
mol new ['09.ala.r46r47.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14682.t.c'].bgf
mol new ['17.ala.r47r48.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c9610.th.c'].bgf
mol new ['18.ala.r48r49.TRK820.no_59.rnd_1.c19106.t.c'].bgf
```

Comment: That's because you're using `splitlines`. Instead of `x=f.readline().splitlines()`, try `x=f.readline().strip()`.

Comment: Thanks, @SIMONSON92, for creating a short, complete example program. Having that complete sample made life much easier for your readers. See [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the splitlines() method on the results of readline()

file.readline() returns one line of the file, including the trailing newline.

.splitlines() is getting rid of the newline by using it as a delimiter and giving you a LIST of lines with only 1 item.  The brackets are coming from the str representation of that 1 item list

you want this:

```
x = f.readline().rstrip()
```

to remove the newline or you could also *slice* off the newline like this

```
x = f.readline()[:-1]
```

another thing you might consider is changing your code to use the file object as an iterable.  It is more idiomatic in Python to write

```
for line in fileobject:
    print line[:-1]
```

than to use a while loop and .readline()

Comment: Wouldn't `line.rstrip()` or even `line.rstrip('\n')` be more idiomatic?

Comment: good question - I did show using .rstrip() in the first part of the answer because I do think it's more obvious that a method named rstrip is going be removing something :-)

Answer (score 4):

Making minimal changes to your code, try:

```
i=1
f=open("name.txt","r")
while(i<=225):
 x=f.readline().rstrip('\n')
 print("mol new %s.bgf"%(x))
 i+=1
f.close()
```

This produces output like:

```
mol new 02.ala.r49r50.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14421.f.c.bgf
mol new 04.ala.r44r45.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c48608.h.c.bgf
mol new 09.ala.r46r47.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c14682.t.c.bgf
mol new 17.ala.r47r48.TRK820.no_0.rnd_1.c9610.th.c.bgf
mol new 18.ala.r48r49.TRK820.no_59.rnd_1.c19106.t.c.bgf
```

Further improvements:

```
with open("name.txt","r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 225:
            break
        print("mol new %s.bgf"%(line.rstrip('\n')))
```

Notes:

1. You want to use `with open("name.txt","r") as f` to assure that the file `f` gets closed regardless.
2. Looping over `i` as a counter as in `i=1; while(i<=225): i+=1` is not pythonic.  Use enumerate instead.
3. `readline` reads in a line.  There is no need for `splitlines`.
4. By looping over the lines in the file with `for i, line in enumerate(f):`, we eliminate the need to read the whole file in at once.  This makes the program suitable for handling very large files.
5. In python, when a line is read from a file, it still has the newline at the end of it.  We use `rstrip('\n')` to safely remove it.

Answer (score 3):

The `readline` function reads a single line from the file. Then you ask to split the line into a ***list*** of lines (which will give you a list of only one line since that's what you have).

Don't split the *single line*. Instead *strip* the string (to remove leading and trailing "white-space").

Please read [the string reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for more information about both [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) and [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: What solution do you propose?

Comment: I was wondering how to implement that in code. I now understand with your new edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because `f.readline().splitlines()` returns the line in a list form containing a single element.

Try this instead:

```
x = f.readline().splitlines()
x = x[0]
```

Comment: @Robᵩ Yup... sorry, I tested on `"[string]"` instead of `["string"]`